# Index dataframe based on row and col info in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to try and select the correct index row and column based on information from another dataframe. I have a list of the correct index numbers ['index_nums'] in dataframe (df_one) and on the same rows is their names under ['names'], 'John','Sam','Peter', etc. These names are column headers in another dataframe (df_two). I want to say, from df_one, if 'index_nums' equals the index row in df_two, AND the 'names' equals the column header in df_two. Extract this particular value in a new column in df_one.

df_one:

```
    ['Index_nums']['Names']
           3        Sam
           4        John
           5        Steve
```

df_two:

```
     ['John']  ['Sam']   ['Steve']
 0     23.5      45.4      52.2
 1     33.3      9.9       10.2
 3     22.2      9.0       7.3
 4     12.5      15.5      15.4
 5     24.4      8.2       4.4
 6     15.5      25.1      1.9
```

Expected Output:

df_one:

```
 ['Index_nums'] ['Names'] ['new_col']
        3         Sam       9.0
        4         John      12.5
        5         Steve     4.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html), directly unpacking the columns of `df_one`, so that they are fed as arguments for `lookup`, which expects a sequence of `row_labels` and of `col_labels` respectively:

```
df_one['new_col'] = df_two.lookup(*df_one.values.T)

    Index_nums  Names  new_col
0           3    Sam      9.0
1           4   John     12.5
2           5  Steve      4.4
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't even know about .lookup!

Comment: Great answer, whats the function of the `*` in `lookup`?

Comment: Thanks @erfan. It is unpacking the two columns in `df_one`, so that they are fed as arguments of the `lookup` function, which expects a sequence of indices and one of columns respectively. Added some more details

Comment: Btw not sure why, but I get different output when I run the same code for `new_col`